# Custom 'Add to Cart' Buttons Underneath Products In Featured Collection Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I am working on customizing the Shopify 'Debut' theme, creating a customizable homepage section off of the existing "Featured Collection". The basic format of the section is a row of 4 horizontal product images from the selected collection with the title and price underneath the photos. Right under the price, I want to be able to add a custom 'Add to Cart' button from a .png asset file that lines up under each individual product image.

So far, I have used this code snippet to place my 4 custom buttons on the page, but I cannot get  them to format correctly so they line up perfectly under each photo's title and price:

```
<div>
 <a href=“#”><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0559/2871/7472/t/1/assets/ROLL_OVER_CTA_BUTTON.png?v=6917840547249396695" width="300"></a>
<a href=“#”><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0559/2871/7472/t/1/assets/ROLL_OVER_CTA_BUTTON.png?v=6917840547249396695" width="300"></a>
<a href=“#”><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0559/2871/7472/t/1/assets/ROLL_OVER_CTA_BUTTON.png?v=6917840547249396695" width="300"></a>
<a href=“#”><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0559/2871/7472/t/1/assets/ROLL_OVER_CTA_BUTTON.png?v=6917840547249396695" width="300"></a>
</div>
```

This is the original code that seems to be the product image, title, and price display in a grid:

```
    {%- assign product_limit = section.settings.grid | times: section.settings.rows -%}

  <ul class="grid grid--uniform grid--view-items">
    {% for product in collection.products limit: product_limit %}
      <li class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
        {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: max_height, product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
      </li>
    {% else %}

      {% for i in (1..product_limit) %}
        <li id="list" class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
          <div class="grid-view-item product-card">
          <!-- <a class="grid-view-item__link grid-view-item__image-container full-width-link" href="#">
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</span>
            </a>-->
            <div class="grid-view-item__image-wrapper">
              {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
              {{ 'product-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
            </div>
            <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title" aria-hidden="true">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</div>
           {% include 'product-price' %}
          </div>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

How can I achieve this layout? It would also be really helpful to have the image button automatically show up under all products in the section in case another row of 4 was added underneath.

Any help is much appreciated in advance.